# Library for PARAFAC decomposition

Tags: c++, decomposition

I am looking for a C++ library that can do [PARAFAC decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PARAFAC) or [Tucker3 decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tucker_decomposition). I need it to do an EEG signal analysis.

Comment: I remember having coded an ALS (not for PARAFAC, but the problem solved was very close, and probably equivalent: in dimension 2 it boils down to SVD), and it was a pain in the *ss regarding convergence robustness. Good luck.